# Is it possible to not show \xrefitem pages in the top level treeview?

Tags: doxygen

I'm using ALIAS and \xrefitem to gather a specific list of comments into a separate page for reference. This is working fine, however, each of these specific pages appear in the top level treeview. For other page/subpage hierarchies I've built a MarkDown index page that shows in the top level, and then references the others, thus keeping my treeview neat. I've done the same for the xrefitem pages, and the index page works fine, but the xrefitem pages still appear in the top level treeview.

Is there any way I can stop this, to keep my treeview clean?

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a markdown file (or work it into your existing mainpage):

```
Scratch                 {#mainpage}
==================================


\subpage custom
\xrefitem xrefitem_subpage "xrefitem Heading" "xrefitem Title" Item to document

\page custom My Custom Pages
\subpage xrefitem_subpage

\page xrefitem_subpage Key Three Page
Some Text
```